# Adjusting layout of android activity to fit all screens and always display all information

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

[image]

I have the above layout in my application, however I am using a Note 3 as the test device and whenever I make the design it's too big for most other phones. Here is my XML file.

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"

    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Wynik:    "
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="0/0"
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/firstbutton"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/answera"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:onClick="Clicking"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />


</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/secondbutton"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstbutton">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/answerb"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:onClick="Clicking"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:id="@+id/thirdbutton"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_below="@id/secondbutton">
       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="New Button"
           android:id="@+id/answerc"
           android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
           android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
           android:shadowDx="0"
           android:shadowDy="0"
           android:shadowRadius="5"
           android:textSize="18dp"
           android:onClick="Clicking"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="23dp">

       </Button></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/fourthbutton"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/thirdbutton">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/answerd"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:onClick="Clicking"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>




    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize = "16sp"
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the layout to fit on any phone size and automatically readjust so that the first button is always below the text, all the buttons are evenly spread out with a space between them and the last button is always above the text on the bottom, with the font adjusted accordingly. I'm not sure how to accomplish this with my XML.

UPDATE :

```html
Process: com.example.albert.mathapp, PID: 3832
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.albert.mathapp/com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class Button
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class Button
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:464)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1415)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:56)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:97)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:782)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:810)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using weights rather than setting heights.  In the example below I used your example (removed the backgrounds I do not have) and set the weights for each layout holding the button to a weight of 1.  I also set the parent of the layouts to match the parent so the layouts holding the button will adjust their size dependent on their parent size.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Wynik:    "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="0/0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answera"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:onClick="Clicking"
                android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answerb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:onClick="Clicking"
                android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answerc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:onClick="Clicking"
                android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answerd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:onClick="Clicking"
                android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you suggest I also set the font size to ?android:attr/textAppearance... so that it automatically adjusts to fit the button?

Comment: Whats up @Alk good question.  I would try that and let me know if it works. I am not entirely sure about it but in the mean time I will do some research.

Comment: @Alk Hey did it work out with the  ?android:attr/textAppearance

Comment: Okay the error is in line 54 of your xml layout file.  What is that?

Comment: That line is just            <Button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78957/discussion-between-alk-and-eugene-h).

Comment: Okay then there is an error within that <Button></Button> post that button to your question.